# html text is not properly formatted

Tags: asp.net, html

I am looking for an output like below using html

Creative agency:(?) *

I am writing the code something like below...

```
    <td class="TextLabelForHeader" width="300px">

     Creative Agency:<h6 id="/contracts/HelpContent/Creative%20Agency.txt">()</h6>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorCreativeAgency" runat="server"
                                 ControlToValidate="txtCreativeAgency" ErrorMessage="*"  ValidationGroup="VGPageGeneral">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </td>
```

But I am getting the output something like below in broswer...

Creative agency:
               (?)
               *

Can please someone help me with this....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header tags, such as `H6` are block elements. Block elements take up the entire width of their containers.

Either:

Make `H6` an inline element using CSS: `h6 {display:inline};`

or

Use the semantically-correct HTML element for this purpose, in this case a `<label>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace your h6 with an inline element e.g `<span>`

```
Creative Agency:<span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14pt" id="/contracts/HelpContent/Creative%20Agency.txt">()</span>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorCreativeAgency" runat="server"
                             ControlToValidate="txtCreativeAgency" ErrorMessage="*"  ValidationGroup="VGPageGeneral">
```

`h1..h6` are block element and they occupy all available space of their container forcing other elements in the container to go to next line.

If I may ask why do you have such a funny `id` on your h6?